# Spree - undefined local variable or method `meta_data_tags' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have this line in my `layouts/application.html.erb` file

```
<%== meta_data_tags unless content_for? :head %>
```

and I am getting

> undefined local variable or method `meta_data_tags'

error

my `apllication_controller.rb`

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers
    include Spree::Core::Engine.helpers
    include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers
    include Spree::AuthenticationHelpers
  end
```

Could anyone help me fix this issue?

```
$ spree version
2.2.13

$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.13

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [x86_64-linux]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: see if it help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/JhsxcT648Cg

Comment: @DeepakMahakale that fixed the issue. Many thanks